# Framework + Client Code references

Tags: .net, dependencies, reference, teamcity

We are simultaniously working on a base-framework and on a implementation (little test tool) on top of it. 
There are several things I'd like, and I am wondering if they are all possible:

(.NET 3.5, VS2008)

- Have a .sln with only the implementation (tool) - project
- Have a .sln with tool + framework projects
- Have a .sln with only framework projects

Have a build server (Team City) with 2 build configs:
- Framework
- Tool

Now while this can probably all work while referencing just .dll's between tool and framework, I would like to work on the framework from within the tool+framework solution, without being confronted with [Metadata] code files constantly.

Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

Is that possible to join all projects in one big solution? You may have several .sln files referencing same .csproj(or whatever) files.